# DexClassLoader - invoke method with parameter

Tags: java, android, classloader, nosuchmethoderror

I have met some tutorials on the web, which are invoking simple methods and all I need is to invoke method "startDownload" which accepts Context as a parameter. I am now calling it:

```
Class<?> loaded = cl.loadClass("com.test.someclass");
Method m = loaded.getDeclaredMethod("startDownload", null);
m.invoke(this, null);
```

where c1 is DexClassLoader. But no success. I am getting error of NoSuchMethodException, I know I have to add parametres somewhere, but don't know where... any advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking at [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857807/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-library-at-runtime-from-an-android-applicati).

The parameters are passed after the method name when calling `Class.getMethod(name, ...)`, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E...%29). You can directly use the `class` member of the `Class` you have to pass:

```
Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("doSomethingWithAString", String.class);
```

Maybe you forgot some of them: the method won't be found if the signature (so the parameters) are not correct.