# Can android apps be extended by third parties?

Tags: android, plugins

I want to know if an android app of mine can be extended by third parties *without* me *having to modify the base app for each extension*, kind of what eclipse does with its plug-ins.

The base app would be something pretty simple, some kind of local data manager (CRUD operations). A given plug-in may, for example, do things with said data (different ways of displaying it, for instance) in additional activities/fragments.

From a little research around, I've discovered that if I were to be the developer of both base app and plug-ins, I could accomplish it by creating new apks non directly accessible for the user (Main/Launcher) and querying from the base app whether a given plug-in is installed on the device and, if so, show additional options on the UX. I can work with that, but I wondered if there was no other option to allow the third-party extension.

Searching for "extension points" doesn't seem to yield android results. Maybe it isn't possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A given plug-in may, for example, do things with said data (different ways of displaying it, for instance) in additional activities/fragments.

Step #1: Expose said data to third-party apps, such as via a `ContentProvider`.

Right now, you're already done, except for the part of "show additional options on the UX". For that:

Step #2: Document the `<intent-filter>` that third-party apps should have on any activities that they want to be launched from your app. This may involve custom actions and/or categories and/or MIME types.

Step #3: When your needs to "show additional options on the UX" (which I am interpreting as some sort of list or menu), use `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager` to find all activities that implemented the `<intent-filter>` that you documented in Step #2, and include them in that list.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular scenario, where it's simply a matter of storing and retrieving data from a base application, you can use the same approach as the Contacts application uses, which uses a Content Provider.

You can read more about Content Providers and how to implement them here: [Content Providers | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

If you're instead looking at extending an installed application, you would have to predefine a dynamic set of classes to present the data, as well as a set of rules and a language / interface for the plug-ins to extend your applications functionality from within your own application.

You could also look into loading external .jar files into your application at runtime. [It looks like others have been successful before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857807/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-library-at-runtime-from-an-android-applicat)