# How to distribute apps to selected users

Tags: android, ios, win-universal-app

in my company we plan to develop  an app with different modules. We develop Apps for Apple, Android and Windows. We have some default modules like inventory and relocation, but for some customers, we need to develop custom modules. The question is, what is the best way to provide this app to our customers and how we can use update functions?

If we build one app with every module, and just unlock the modules based on the customers licence, it will be massive inflated, at the time. We have up to 20 customers and each of it needs 2 or 3 custom modules.

To build 20+ apps and distribute it over the store, it will be really difficult to manage each app. And if we update some core functions, every single app must be updated. Not a good way.

So what is the best way to develop custom apps for our customers and ditribute and update it?

sorry for my english, it's not the best..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't want to include all modules in every app installation, and you don't want to distribute many different versions of the app, each one with a different combination of modules.

It seems to me that the only solution you have is to download your modules after the user has installed the app and chosen their license.

The easiest way to implement this is with a web app as opposed to a native app. However if you want to write a native app you are able to download and execute binaries at runtime.

This thread contains a few different approaches to achieve that:

[Is it possible to dynamically load a library at runtime from an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857807/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-library-at-runtime-from-an-android-applicat)

Good luck!