# Access execute Android code remotely

Tags: android, remote-access

This will be a tricky one, I don't know it's even possible. So I am writing an application ,where after login the user can have access for some sensitive data. If the user belongs to a VIP group than she has access to more sensitive data (such as market reports). In order to provide maximum security we want to extract VIP related code (activity, layouts, backend calls) and only download, when a user really need it. 
The solution should be native android, so opening a webView within the app is not a solution for us.

I am looking for something such as "*Android Instant Apps*", but we have to be independent from Google to provide our own service.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Extract functionality into a separate JAR file, convert it to DEX and load dynamically using `DexClassLoader`.

There are plenty of questions at SO which covers the topic. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6860579/648313