# Android app with lots of external libraries vs application size

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have an android app with a few external libraries (also native) and I will have to add another ones. My app is growing which becomes a real problem. 
Single library is used by less than 5% of my app users so I do not want to force all my users to install app with all the libraries that they do not need. In fact most of my users do not need any of these libraries.

I was wthinking about expansion files (https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) but as far as I know this doesn't solve my problem as in most cases all the expansion files are downloaded with application anyway.

Is there a solution that allows my to download external code on the go?

Marcin

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6860579/2724879

Comment: As you already told that you are using native libraries, so I believe that , there are several version of those libraries based on cpu structure like armbei,amrbei-v7a, am I right ? and one more thing , you are concerned about the apk size , right ?

Comment: some of the libraries are native, some not. And yes - I need several versions based on cpu architecture

Comment: Technically should work but what about Google rules? https://play.google.com/intl/en-GB/about/developer-content-policy-print/   An app distributed via Google Play may not modify, replace or update itself using any method other than Google Play’s update mechanism. Likewise, an app may not download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play. This restriction does not apply to code that runs in a virtual machine and has limited access to Android APIs (such as JavaScript in a WebView or browser).