# Class not found exception using reflection on class saved in device on Android

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm playing with reflection on Android. I've saved JAR file on device and I'm trying to get class from this JAR but it isn't working and I'm getting exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.class
```

My code:

```
File classFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator);
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { classFile.toURI().toURL() });
Class classToInvestigate = classLoader.loadClass("Main.class");
```

Also I tried saved there Main.class file, but I'm still getting errors. Is there something I'm missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**The way you load a class is as follow:**

```
Class<?> stringBuilder = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("java.lang.StringBuilder");
```

**Another approach:**

```
Class.forName("java.lang.StringBuilder");
```

**UPDATED:** Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6860579/1715121

Take a look at the FQCN of Main class.

Comment: Still not working. I have HelloWorld.jar only with package com.helloworld and class Main. I've changed code to `.loadClass("com.helloworld.Main");` but same error.

Comment: Answer updated: `Class.forName("java.lang.StringBuilder");`

Comment: But this JAR is saved on device and I need to get this JAR first with his location and then somehow look for name, am I wrong?

Comment: Every class will be loaded on demand for the class loader, regardless of its location.  When you're calling the method `forName` or method `loadClass` that class will be loaded at runtime.

Comment: Yes, but first of all, I run application, download JAR from URL, save into device and then try to load that class. But also tried and I've this error now:  `Didn't find class "com.helloworld.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/testapp/s-1/base.apk"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160361/discussion-between-vlados24-and-eleazar-enrique).