# How to build an shared library and call it in other ndk program

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to build an shared library. To build it, I need to call another shared library. Here is what I did:

1.Create one Android project,named "BuildLib",and add a new folder "jni" under the project directory. Contents of jni folder:

> jni-->Android.mk
>        -->Application.mk
>        -->add.cpp
>        -->add.h add.cpp just do two numbers addition:

add.h:

> int add(int a,int b);

add.cpp:

> ```
> #include "add.h"  
> int add(int a,int b){
>     return a+b;}
> ```

Android.mk:

> ```
> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := add.cpp 
> LOCAL_MODULE     := add
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```

After build the project,I got libadd.so under directory `$(BUILDLIB)/libs/armeabi/`.

Create another Android project, named "CallLib". Copy `libadd.so` and `add.h` to jni folder, create `Android.mk`, `Application.mk`, and `call_add.cpp`.

Android.mk:

> ```
> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libadd.so
> LOCAL_MODULE := add_prebuilt
> include $(PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH）
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := call_add.cpp 
> LOCAL_MODULE     :=  native
> LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := add_prebuilt
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```

call_add.cpp:

> ```
> #include "add.h"
> int call_add(){return add(1,2);}
> ```

After all above, I build the CallLib project, but got the error:

> undefined reference to 'add(int, int)';

I think the `libadd.so` can not be found, but I don't know how to modify. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You were using Eclipse for compiling right???
I am really stuck with this in Android Studio.
If you are any idea about how to do this in Android Studio, let me know.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358210/how-to-create-a-shared-library-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second `Android.mk`, try replacing the first module with:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libadd.so
LOCAL_MODULE := add_prebuilt
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := add.h
include $(PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` flag should attach the header information to the `add_prebuilt` module, so it can be linked with your final library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm too careless, It's should be "PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY" not "PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY".The process above is right absolutely,except this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone needs it:

A bit hackish way to keep the linker happy:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

or

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib -lMyStuff
```

Less hackish:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := xyz
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += xyz/xyz.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)    # this builds libxyz.so


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := abc
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := xyz    # <=== !!! this makes libabc.so dependent on libxyz.so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := abc/abc.c
#LOCAL_LDLIBS := ...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)    # this builds libabc.so
```