# Integrating MuPDF as a library project (Android)

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-intent, android-ndk

So I have built this project based on a pdf reader(MuPDF). I used ndk-build for that. The name of this project is ChoosePDFActivity. I know that it has been correctly built because I can see a .so file inside my **libs/armrabi-v7a/THISISTHEFILE.so**.
My question is, how do i Correctly make this project a library project and run it from another project ?

I tried marking it as a library project and adding it to my main project's build path, but I get

**Note that I am using Mupdf-1.5(the latest one currently)**

> ExpressionInitializerError , could not load library , FindLibrary
>   Returned NUll errors

so what do I do ?

the name of my library is libmupdf. 
Note, I am new to android-ndk. I dont have any jni folder in my main project, only in the library project.
This is the full error.

> 06-16 17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-16 17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 06-16 17:51:27.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native
>   Method) 06-16 17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 06-16 17:51:27.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1025)
>   06-16 17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
>   06-16 17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   06-16 17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 06-16
>   17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   06-16 17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-16
>   17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-16 17:51:27.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 06-16
>   17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-16
>   17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-16 17:51:27.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
>   06-16 17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592) 06-16
>   17:51:27.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-16 17:51:27.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5673): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   Couldn't load libmupdf: findLibrary returned null 06-16 17:51:27.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365) 06-16 17:51:27.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535) 06-16 17:51:27.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5673):   at
>   com.mainpackage.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:44)

Please help me, its killing me for a couple of days. Thanks in advance.

this is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TOP_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

MUPDF_ROOT := ../..

ifdef NDK_PROFILER
include android-ndk-profiler.mk
endif

include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/Core.mk
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/ThirdParty.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    jni/andprof \
    $(MUPDF_ROOT)/include \
    $(MUPDF_ROOT)/source/fitz \
    $(MUPDF_ROOT)/source/pdf
LOCAL_CFLAGS :=
LOCAL_MODULE    := mupdf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mupdf.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := mupdfcore mupdfthirdparty
ifdef NDK_PROFILER
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -pg -DNDK_PROFILER
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += andprof
else
endif

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics
ifdef SSL_BUILD
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -L$(MUPDF_ROOT)/thirdparty/openssl/android -lcrypto -lssl
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is a snapshot of my projects.There are two highlighted projects, they are the ones being talked about, with ChoosePDFActivity being the library project. 
[image],
**Okay, just something like this is going to work for my case:
Is it possible to have a Whole project inside my final build?I just need to pass ONE intent to it from my main project, and everything else is going to be handled by the ChoosePdf...** project.

**P.S.**
I noticed that there is a armeabi-v7a only. So , is there any way to build mupdf for other architectures as well

**EDIT
For those who want to have PDF rendering in android, Android L has (finally) got the apis to make native pdf rendering possible.**

Answer (score 2):

You just have to create a dummy dynamic library that simply links against your static library like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957386/892714

The ndk build system (unfortunately) will not create a static library without it being used by a dynamic library.  Then you simply grab your static library from obj/local/armeabi-v7a.

Comment: That is, unless you just want to use your dynamic library as is.  If that's the case, just copy it to <your_project>/lib/armeabi-v7a/ and it will be included.  You can then call System.loadLibrary("THISISTHEFILE");

Comment: did so, and got this error: 

[2014-06-17 09:13:59 - Marks++] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi-v7a/libmupdf.so
Origin 1: C:\Users\Harsh\git\marks\Marks++\libs\armeabi-v7a\libmupdf.so
Origin 2: C:\muPDFLIB\mupdf-1.5-source\platform\android\libs\armeabi-v7a\libmupdf.so

Comment: please post your Android.mk file.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need any NDK magic because if your project has no `jni/` folder, and if you place the libraries in the `libs/`, they will be there. (Just in case, put them under version control; by default .so is usually ignored.)

The most important line in your log is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libmupdf
```

If your project uses two libraries, you have to load both, in the order that would resolve dependencies.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("tools"); // libtools.so
    System.loadLibrary("main"); // libmain.so
}
```

As I understand, you have no linker problems, but just in case I post these links:
[Re: How to build an shared library and call it in other ndk program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24138372/755804)
[Android NDK - make two native shared libraries calling each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688327/android-ndk-make-two-native-shared-libraries-calling-each-other)
[Android NDK: Link using a pre-compiled static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463518/android-ndk-link-using-a-pre-compiled-static-library)

Comment: okay, I am totally new to this. Didnt really get you. 
what do you mean by placing the libraries in the libs/ folder ?
does that mean the .so file  ?

Comment: I added a pic of my project tree ,please see it

Comment: "in the libs/" means libs/armeabi-v7a/THISISTHEFILE.so is ok. (nore that you have a typo in libs/arm*r*abi-v7a/THISISTHEFILE.so)

Comment: did you _loadLibrary()_ ?

Comment: okay , here is some more info for clarification, I tried loading library from my main project, and it doesnt work. As for the libs/ type, i did NOT change anything , it was as is from the project(ChoosePdfActivity).

Comment: ***tried loading library from my main project, and it doesnt work*** -- what is the error message? If another library is missing, you have to load that too. Try to start with a library from the hello-jni example. In addition, Eclipse sometimes ignores the dependencies, so build/=rebuild.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55897/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-18446744073709551615).

Comment: What is in the ***Caused by*** part?