# Using MuPDF in android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have just started learning android programming. I want to use the MuPDF library for android. Unfortunately, I am unable to get any proper documentation.

I tried running `ndk- build`, but it generates libs for only armeabi-v7. I need To view pdf in android (and all architectures).

So how do I go about it ?

Comment: What have you searched so far? Above explanation is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at my question [Integrating MuPDF as a library project (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243919/integrating-mupdf-as-a-library-project-android).

While that might not be so helpful to solve your problem, you will get to know what you are dealing with. Aside of this, you must add the  `APP_ABI=all` argument to build for other architectures.