# How to download a file from http using C?

Tags: html, c, file, sockets, tcp

I spent the last days trying to figure out how to download a file from an URL.
This is my first challenge with socket and I'm using it to have an understanding of protocols so I would like to do it without cURL libraries and only in C language!!
I searched a lot....now I'm able to printf the source code of a page but I think it's different with a file, I don't have only to put the received data from a buffer to a file, right?
any tips?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
    char domain[] = "www.sstatic.net", path[]="stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png"; //example 
    int sock, bytes_received;  
    char send_data[1024],recv_data[9999], *p;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent *he;
    FILE *fp;

    he = gethostbyname(domain);
    if (he == NULL){
       herror("gethostbyname");
       exit(1);
    }

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))== -1){
       perror("Socket");
       exit(1);
    }
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1){
       perror("Connect");
       exit(1); 
    }

    snprintf(send_data, sizeof(send_data), "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: /%s\r\n\r\n", path, domain);
    //printf("%s\n", send_data);
    send(sock, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0); 
    printf("Data sended.\n");  

    fp=fopen("received_file","wb");

    bytes_received = recv(sock, recv_data, 9999, 0);
    recv_data[bytes_received] = '\0';
    printf("Data receieved.\n");
    printf("%s\n", recv_data);

    p = strstr(recv_data, "\r\n\r\n");  //to find "\r\n\r\n" sequence and put the pointer p after that
    p=p+4;

    fwrite(p,strlen(p),1,fp);       

    close(sock);
    fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 1** thanks to milevyo for some improvements!
It works good with a txt file but it doesn't with other kinds of file (png in this case)

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void){

    //char domain[] = "www.gnu.org", path[]="/licenses/gpl.txt"; //example 
    char domain[] = "sstatic.net", path[]="stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png"; //example 
        int sock, bytes_received;  
    char send_data[1024],recv_data[9999];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent *he;
    FILE *fp;

    he = gethostbyname(domain);
    if (he == NULL){
       herror("gethostbyname");
       exit(1);
    }

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))== -1){
       perror("Socket");
       exit(1);
    }
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 

    printf("Connecting ...\n");
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1){
       perror("Connect");
       exit(1); 
    }

    printf("Sending data ...\n");

    snprintf(send_data, sizeof(send_data), "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: /%s\r\n\r\n", path, domain);

    if(send(sock, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0)==-1){
        perror("send");
        exit(2); 
    }
    printf("Data sent.\n");  

    fp=fopen("received_file","wb");
    printf("Recieving data...\n\n");
    while((bytes_received = recv(sock, recv_data, 9999, 0))>0){
        if(bytes_received==-1){
            perror("recieve");
            exit(3);
        }
        recv_data[bytes_received] = '\0';

        fwrite(recv_data,bytes_received,1,fp);
        printf("%s", recv_data);
    }



    close(sock);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

this code produce a 334 bytes file (instead of 12,4kb of the original file) with this inside:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2015 16:20:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 177
Connection: close
Server: -nginx
CF-RAY: -

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

somebody knows how to fix this "400 Bad Request"?

Comment: Note that `send()` and `recv()` may not send or receive all data at once and they may be needed to be called repeatedly.

Comment: Do not use `strlen()` to calculate the length of binary file.

Comment: You need to handle the HTTP headers too, if you don't then it might be using *gzip* encoding for example, and other problems too like a chunked encoding. It's not so hard to write a simple HTTP client, and then when you handle headers you can even know what mime type the file has and it's length and other useful information.

Comment: You want to scan through the new HTTP RFCs 7230-7235 and learn the relevant parts on file transfer: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/

Comment: But first do some more basic socket exercises, using less complex protocols, probably also writing your own server which just sends you a laaaarge file.

Comment: first of all thanks for the answers!
----1) So I have to put send() and recv() in a cycle, both? or only recv() with fwrite()?
But for this simple example 9999 of buffer should be ok?
----2) And what I should use for the length of the buffer?
----3) Unfortunately there are a plenty of documentation about that and my real problem it's to find what I really need! How can I narrow my research?

Comment: Read `man 3 recv()` closly and learn the function not necessarily returns the number of bytes it was told to. **ALWAYS** check `recv()`'s return value. Which you should do any ways when calling functions which could fail.

Comment: The defacto reference on socket programming is Stevens (rip) http://unpbook.com/ (or its updates) Take it, read it, love it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an update for the previous posted code. The http protocol is far to be implementation in just a small example.

reformatting the code , or giving a modification to it is more than welcome.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <string.h>


int ReadHttpStatus(int sock){
    char c;
    char buff[1024]="",*ptr=buff+1;
    int bytes_received, status;
    printf("Begin Response ..\n");
    while(bytes_received = recv(sock, ptr, 1, 0)){
        if(bytes_received==-1){
            perror("ReadHttpStatus");
            exit(1);
        }

        if((ptr[-1]=='\r')  && (*ptr=='\n' )) break;
        ptr++;
    }
    *ptr=0;
    ptr=buff+1;

    sscanf(ptr,"%*s %d ", &status);

    printf("%s\n",ptr);
    printf("status=%d\n",status);
    printf("End Response ..\n");
    return (bytes_received>0)?status:0;

}

//the only filed that it parsed is 'Content-Length' 
int ParseHeader(int sock){
    char c;
    char buff[1024]="",*ptr=buff+4;
    int bytes_received, status;
    printf("Begin HEADER ..\n");
    while(bytes_received = recv(sock, ptr, 1, 0)){
        if(bytes_received==-1){
            perror("Parse Header");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(
            (ptr[-3]=='\r')  && (ptr[-2]=='\n' ) &&
            (ptr[-1]=='\r')  && (*ptr=='\n' )
        ) break;
        ptr++;
    }

    *ptr=0;
    ptr=buff+4;
    //printf("%s",ptr);

    if(bytes_received){
        ptr=strstr(ptr,"Content-Length:");
        if(ptr){
            sscanf(ptr,"%*s %d",&bytes_received);

        }else
            bytes_received=-1; //unknown size

       printf("Content-Length: %d\n",bytes_received);
    }
    printf("End HEADER ..\n");
    return  bytes_received ;

}

int main(void){

    char domain[] = "sstatic.net", path[]="stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png"; 

    int sock, bytes_received;  
    char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024], *p;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent *he;


    he = gethostbyname(domain);
    if (he == NULL){
       herror("gethostbyname");
       exit(1);
    }

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))== -1){
       perror("Socket");
       exit(1);
    }
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 

    printf("Connecting ...\n");
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1){
       perror("Connect");
       exit(1); 
    }

    printf("Sending data ...\n");

    snprintf(send_data, sizeof(send_data), "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", path, domain);

    if(send(sock, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0)==-1){
        perror("send");
        exit(2); 
    }
    printf("Data sent.\n");  

    //fp=fopen("received_file","wb");
    printf("Recieving data...\n\n");

    int contentlengh;

    if(ReadHttpStatus(sock) && (contentlengh=ParseHeader(sock))){

        int bytes=0;
        FILE* fd=fopen("test.png","wb");
        printf("Saving data...\n\n");

        while(bytes_received = recv(sock, recv_data, 1024, 0)){
            if(bytes_received==-1){
                perror("recieve");
                exit(3);
            }


            fwrite(recv_data,1,bytes_received,fd);
            bytes+=bytes_received;
            printf("Bytes recieved: %d from %d\n",bytes,contentlengh);
            if(bytes==contentlengh)
            break;
        }
        fclose(fd);
    }



    close(sock);
    printf("\n\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've only added `fwrite(recv_data,bytes_received,1,fp);` and it works with a txt file!!
 But what I have to do to make it works with other files?

Comment: it should work with any type of data, just make sure you open file in binary mode.

Comment: This is binary `fp=fopen("received_file","wb");` , right?

Comment: question about binary mode, yes. but manually renaming the file?. you can do that from your code, just create the output file by the desired name

Comment: of course I can do `fp=fopen("received_file.png","wb");` or using a string for the name of the file, but the point is that it doesn't work anyway! The function doesn't save a readable png file!! It works good with txt file but not with other kind of file!!

Comment: if I use `char domain[] = "www.sstatic.net", path[]="stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png";`
I receive a 334 bytes file with:
`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2015 04:41:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 177
Connection: close
Server: -nginx
CF-RAY: -

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: that because there is no `www.sstatic.net` change it to `sstatic.net`. keep in mind that you have to parse the HTTP header, to get the success or the error of your request. this can not be handled here.

Comment: you also can be little bit kind to accept my answer, if you find it useful

Comment: man!! `www.sstatic.net` or `sstatic.net` produce the same result....the same unreadable file! The answer make some useful improvement but it doesn't solve the problem!!

Comment: i see, you are unaware of HTTP protocol, because you never tried to skip header or parse it.  now, i updated my code to give you an idea how it should be parsed to get files downloaded from an http server. wish this can better help.

Comment: sorry for my incompetence and thank you very much for your time!! Now I hope I will find a way to understand it and focus myself in research!!

Comment: Hello, has there been any updates or final version of this snipp allowing to download any file for any location and that is compatible with latest android/ndk versions?

Comment: your target is always a *NIX platform, or you need a cross-platform code (Windows included)?

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like below: -

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define BUFLEN 4096
#define HOST "www.t.edu.pk"
#define PORT 443

int main()
{
    int sock, iResult;
    char *cmd, *ip;
    char recvbuf[BUFLEN];
    //
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    struct hostent* hent;
    //
    hent = gethostbyname(HOST);
    if(hent == NULL)
    {
        printf("gethostbyname failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("gethostbyname succeeded\n");
    ip = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)hent->h_addr_list[0]));
    printf("Host IP: %s\n", ip);
    //
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        printf("socket failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("socket created\n");
    //
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    sin.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    iResult = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    if(iResult < 0)
    {
        printf("connect failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("connect succeeded\n");
    //
    iResult = SSL_library_init();
    if(iResult < 0)
    {
        printf("SSL failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("SSL library initialised\n");
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());
    if(ctx == NULL)
    {
        printf("ctx failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("ctx loaded\n");
    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    if(ssl == NULL)
    {
        printf("ssl failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("ssl loaded\n");
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);
    SSL_connect(ssl);
    //
    cmd = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.t.edu.pk\r\n\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    do
    {
        iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
        if(iResult < 0)
        {
            printf("error receiving data\n");
            break;
        }
        if(iResult == 0)
        {
            printf("host closed connection\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    }while(iResult > 0);
    //
    iResult = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    if(iResult == 0)
    {
        printf("SSL shutdown in progress...\n");
    }
    iResult = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    if(iResult == 1)
    {
        printf("SSL shutdown complete!\n");
    }
    if(iResult == -1)
    {
        printf("SSL shutdown unsuccessful!\n");
    }
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    //
    iResult = shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    if(iResult == -1)
    {
        printf("Socket shutdown failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Socket shutdown succeeded\n");
    iResult = close(sock);
    if(iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("error closing socket: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Socket closed\n");
    //
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for C/C++ in linux Environment. You can run it by makefile, or just add -lcurl option in g++.

Notice that should have lib cURL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
 

FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "file_downloaded.txt";
FILE *fp1 = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};


static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    char *ptr = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if(!ptr) {
        /* out of memory! */
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%ld - %ld - %ld\n", realsize, size, nmemb);
    size_t written = fwrite(contents, size, nmemb, fp1);

    mem->memory = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}


int main(void)
{
    char link_download[] = "https://www.example.com/";
    CURL *curl_handle;
    CURLcode res;

    struct MemoryStruct chunk;

    chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
    chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* init the curl session */
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    /* specify URL to get */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, link_download);

    /* send all data to this function  */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

    /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

    /* some servers do not like requests that are made without a user-agent
        field, so we provide one */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

    /* get it! */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    else {
        /*
        * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
        * bytes big and contains the remote file.
        *
        * Do something nice with it!
        */

        printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (unsigned long)chunk.size);
    }
 
    /* cleanup curl stuff */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

    free(chunk.memory);

    /* we are done with libcurl, so clean it up */
    curl_global_cleanup();

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);

    return 0;
}
```