# Linking third party libraries in android ndk eclipse

Tags: android, android-ndk, glib

I have compiled glib library(created a libglib.so file with local_module as libglib) in android ndk eclipse. But I am getting `could not be resolved errors` for the inbuilt functions of glib.

This is my android.mk file:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
    LOCAL_MODULE    := mycode
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mycode.c
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libglib 
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../glib/
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../glib/glib/

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change it to

```
 LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := glib # for libglib.so
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24138372/755804 , that stuff worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Android.mk should be like this :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libglib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../glib/glib.c
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../glib/
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mycode
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/../glib/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mycode.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libglib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The first part build the `libglib.so`.
Then you can make your module `mycode` depend on it.

Comment: It says that local_src_files should end with .so. In my case .so file for glib is built on the go. Hence, there is no libglib.so at the beginning.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstand your question. In this case change the first part of my answer. Change the line `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../glib/` to `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../glib/glib.c` (or the appropriate src file for building libglib.so). Then change the line  `include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)` to `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`.

Comment: I edit my answer following my comment. Let me know if this work for you.